# R format data frame duplicated ID and redondant information

Tags: r, dataframe, format

From my dataframe, I would need to remove the non useful information labelled as "Not done" and keep the interesting one "Neg" available from one the duplicated ID. Sorry not easy to explain. So, my dataframe below :

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2","A2", "A3","A3", "A3"),
                 Variable1 = c("Neg", "Not Done","Not Done", "Not Done", "Neg", "Not Done", "Not Done", "Not Done", "Not Done"),
                 Variable2 = c("Not Done",  "Neg",  "Not Done", "Neg",  "Not Done", "Not Done", "Not Done", "Not Done", "Not Done"),
                 Variable3 = c("Not Done","Not Done","Neg","Not Done","Not Done","Neg","Not Done","Not Done","Not Done"))
```

An example of the expected output :

```
df_A <- data.frame(ID = c("A1", "A2", "A3"),
                 Variable1 = c("Neg", "Neg", "Not Done"),
                 Variable2 = c("Neg", "Neg", "Not Done"),
                 Variable3 = c("Neg","Neg","Not Done"))
```

As you can see, A3, all the values are "Not Done" and so need to keep it once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution with `which.max()`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(across(.fns = ~ .x[which.max(.x == "Neg")])) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 3 × 4
#   ID    Variable1 Variable2 Variable3
#   <chr> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>
# 1 A1    Neg       Neg       Neg
# 2 A2    Neg       Neg       Neg      
# 3 A3    Not Done  Not Done  Not Done
```

Answer (score 2):

In case there is only `Neg` and `Not Done` I would convert them in `TRUE` and `FALSE` and use `any` an `aggregate`.

```
aggregate(df[-1]=="Neg", df[1], any)
#  ID Variable1 Variable2 Variable3
#1 A1      TRUE      TRUE      TRUE
#2 A2      TRUE      TRUE      TRUE
#3 A3     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
df$ID <- factor(df$ID)
ID <- factor(df$ID)
df <- distinct(df)

neg_find <- function(vector) {
  result <- "Neg" %in% vector
  return(result)
}


final_result_neg <- function(dataframe) {
  t <- tapply(dataframe, ID,neg_find)
  return(t)
}

df2 <- apply(df, 2, final_result_neg)%>%data.frame()

df2$ID <- NULL
df2[df2==TRUE] <- 'Neg'
df2[df2==FALSE] <- 'Not Done'

df2
```